# What's the difference between "lingo" and "jargon"?

Tags: differences, synonyms

To what extent, if any, do *lingo* and *jargon* differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’d use lingo to characterize a style of speaking, characterized by words both newly-minted and appropriated for a specific meaning. For example, using *drag* to mean boring or tedious, *bread* to mean money, or *man* as a form of address all contribute to the lingo of counterculture in the 60s.

Jargon refers to a technical vocabulary that is shorthand for complex or elaborate concepts and practices. In technology, for example, it’s often characterized by acronyms and other terms coined by inventors and innovators. In law, medical practice, and academic research, it’s a combination of terms and concepts owed to history that are often anchored to their language of origin.

Comment: <jag> and <bread> is lingo?

Answer (score 5):

Lingo is another word for jargon, but also a slang term for human language as well (at least in BE).

> We visited Spain but didn't speak the lingo.

This example uses "lingo" to mean "language".

> Working in J2EE is simple once you understand the lingo.

This example uses "lingo" to mean "jargon".

Comment: The usage of _lingo_ to mean (often humorously) a foreign language is reported also from the NOAD.

Comment: I would say foreign language is the most common use in BE, it has slight racist tones = "no-speak-a-de-lingo" from older comedy acts.

Answer (score 3):

*Lingo* is simply a language or dialect used by a specific group of people.

*Jargon* implies that the language is limited to a specific profession or other group *and* that others find it difficult to undersand.

Comment: _Lingo_ is also another term for _jargon_, both in American and British English.

Comment: @Kiamlaluno, while you are right to say that *Lingo* can mean the same as *Jargon*, I agree with @Snumpy on the more common usage of the two terms.

Comment: @Karl @kiamlaluno Lingo can be used in place of Jargon, but not always the other way around. "We visited Spain but we didn't understand the Jargon," would not be acceptable (unless you attended a Spanish conference on a technical matter and their terminology (Jargon) was different.)

Comment: @trideceth12 That is well understood. I was referring to the fact _lingo_ is defined in terms of _jargo_, not vice versa. The second definition you should find in a dictionary is "the vocabulary or jargon of a particular subject or group of people."

Answer (score 2):

For starters, *lingo* has racist and colonialist overtones, unlike *jargon*. *Lingo* is informal, unlike *jargon*. Basically, never use it unless you want to convey that you care nothing for the socially appropriate use of language, and possibly offend any speakers of the mode of speech you are labelling as "lingo".